# Label polygon table with points data that are inside polygon

Tags: postgis

I have polygon data and point data in PostGIS database. I want to add a new column to polygon table that contains some value from point data (one column) if point is inside polygon. If there are multiple points inside polygon I want to add field data from all points in one colum.

Is there any way to do this using postgis?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to the query part of the solution.  You should be able to turn this into an `UPDATE` query.

You did not specify how to combine the collected point attribute values into a single column.  `array_agg` is used here, but you may wish to use a different technique.

```
WITH polys(geom) AS (VALUES
( 'POLYGON ((10 50, 40 50, 40 10, 10 10, 10 50))'::geometry ),
( 'POLYGON ((70 50, 70 10, 40 10, 40 50, 70 50))'::geometry )
),
pts(id, geom) AS (VALUES
( 1, 'POINT (19 39)'::geometry ),
( 2, 'POINT (29 24)'::geometry ),
( 3, 'POINT (50 37)'::geometry ),
( 4, 'POINT (26 4)'::geometry ),
( 5, 'POINT (57 4)'::geometry ),
( 6, 'POINT (66 25)'::geometry )
)
SELECT ids, polys.geom
FROM polys 
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT array_agg(id) AS ids
    FROM pts WHERE ST_Intersects(polys.geom, pts.geom)) AS t ON true;
```